# ca siteminder saml sso proxyrule namespace case can not forward

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, siteminder

everyone
our policyserver is 12.8
and run on redhat
and our sampl sso is ok
and we access application via relaystate ,
and we want to access more applications
and we want to access : https://fed.test.com.cn/test,https://fed.test.com.cn/prd,
we want to judge when is test ,forward to one place ,and judge when is prd ,forward to another place
and our proxyrule is here :

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?cocoon-process type="xslt"?>

<!DOCTYPE nete:proxyrules SYSTEM "file:////app/siteminder/agent/agentfed/secure-proxy/proxy-engine/conf/dtd/proxyrules.dtd">

<!-- Proxy Rules -->
<!-- replace www.example.com with your namespace -->
<nete:proxyrules xmlns:nete="https://fed.test.com.cn/" debug="yes">
<nete:cond criteria="beginswith" type="uri">
<!-- replace /dir1 with an appropriate URI -->
<nete:case value="/test">
<!-- replace http://server1.example.com with the appropriate destination server -->
<nete:forward>https://10.164.29.65$0</nete:forward>
</nete:case>
</nete:cond>
</nete:proxyrules>
```

but when we passed https://fed.test.com/affwebservices/public/saml2assertionconsumer,
we found not  forward to destination server.
so ,where is wrong ,we did not found errors in logs
can anyone help us ?
we are in hurry

Answer (score 1):

Proxy rules don't apply to /affwebservices, that's a different "app" on SPS itself.